# file saving error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:"

Tags: python

I have merged a few csv files and would like to export the final merge. The following code and associated error is occurring. I am using Anaconda3 2019.10 > JupyterLab > Python3.7

```
merge1=pm18.merge(pm17, left_on='bbl', right_on='bbl', how='outer')
merge2=merge1.merge(pm16, left_on='bbl', right_on='bbl', how='outer')

merge3=merge2.merge(pm15, left_on='bbl', right_on='bbl', how='outer')

merge3.to_csv(r'C:\Users\EDraklellis\Desktop\LL84Data\csv_pm_downloads', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

---

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-223-953f59b82be6> in <module>
      1 #i dont know why the third merge gets so big. im gonna export and look at it
----> 2 merge3.to_csv(r'C:\Users\EDraklellis\Desktop\LL84Data\csv_pm_downloads', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3226             decimal=decimal,
   3227         )
-> 3228         formatter.save()
   3229 
   3230         if path_or_buf is None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    181                 self.mode,
    182                 encoding=self.encoding,
--> 183                 compression=self.compression,
    184             )
    185             close = True

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    397         if encoding:
    398             # Encoding
--> 399             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
    400         elif is_text:
    401             # No explicit encoding
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\EDraklellis\\Desktop\\LL84Data\\csv_pm_downloads'
```

Comment: Sounds like either python doesn't have write access to the file or directory, or the file is already open by another program that's blocking write access

Comment: Ensure that your file is not accessed when trying to write to it.

Comment: @G.Anderson how do I allow python to have write access to the file? It is not open